# passing parameters to a funcion: do I need to use an alias?

Tags: python, function

Can I use the same var name when passing a value to a function in Python, like this?:

```
def function(i):
    z=i+1
    print (z)

for i in range (0,100):
    function(i)
```

Or should I do it like this:

```
def function(x):
    z=x+1
    print (z)

for i in range (0,100):
    function(i)
```

what is the best practice?

Comment: The scopes are different, so you can use the same names in this context

Comment: Both snippets should work, and the best practice is probably to name your variables in respect of their content and purpose.

Comment: It does not matter what name you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no technical reason why you should't use it, yet I'd **strongly** suggest to get rid of habit of naming variables like `i` or `f` or so, instead of `number_of_beds_in_reserved_room` (or [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) if you prefer so :). By keeping bad habits with short variable names you save nothing nowadays, yet risk a lot of stepping of variable name shadowing which may be pretty damn hard to debug. RAM is cheap. Your time is not.

Comment: Thanks Marcin! -----